# 0-base and 1-base indexed iterables in the same language? Custom slicing rules?

Tags: python, indexing, slice, iterable

I'm learning Python and today's exercise was about positions in a tiled room. The fact that I had to check if a position was inside the room (in a 1x1 room, 0.0 was considered in and 1.0 was considered out) kept me thinking about 0-base indexing iterables and slicing.

Read some articles and discussions, some pros and cons to each 0-base and 1-base, concerns about slicing, etc. But ultimately the question that got stuck in me and didn't found an answer was:
 Why can't both 0-base and 1-base indexing exist in the same language, and why can't slicing be customized?

Check the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEb9C.png

If I'm indexing the ruler marks, intervals, boundaries, dots, makes sense to start of at 0; rul=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6] would index every mark on my ruler so that accordingly rul[0]=0, rul[5]=5.
If I'm indexing the blue circles, natural number quantities, objects, spans, makes sense to start at 1; cir= [1,2,3,4,5] so that cir[1]=1 and cir[5]=5.

Now, a lot of the discussion was to do with slicing coupled with the indexing and I don't totally understand why.

a ≤ x < b is not so intuitive when dealing with objects ("I want balls 1 up to the the one before 3"), so on one side, you put the finger on what you want and on the other, on what you don't want. But this method does have the neat property of producing neighbor selections that border perfectly, as in [:a][a:b][b:c]. Although in inverse order(-1), the results can be unexpected as it returns values off-by-one from its counterpart like; L=[0,1,2,3,4,5] so that L[1:3]=[1,2] and L[3:1:-1]=[3:2]. So it's consistent with the rule a ≤ x < b, grabbing the lower limit item, but it can feel strange by not producing the same selection with inverse order.

a ≤ x ≤ b is a natural way to select objets ("I want the balls 1 up to 3"), so you're putting the finger on the things you want. If you inverse the order(-1) it's still very easy to grasp what are you picking because whatever you select it's included like: L=[0,1,2,3,4,5] so that L[1:3]=[1,2,3] and L[3:1:-1]=[3,2,1]. Problems seem to arrive though, when trying to do neighbor selections, where one would have to do [:a][a+1:b][b+1:c] to have the border perfectly. That terrible?

Even though one could see a ≤ x < b to be more adept to 0-base, and a ≤ x ≤ b to be more adept to 1-base, the way I see it, index base and slicing rules could be somehow independent. And one would index and slice the way it would fit the rationale of the problem or the data, because even slicing a 1-base indexed array with a ≤ x < b, would still produce an expected outcome, as in cir=[1,2,3,4,5] so that cir[1:3]=[1,2] or cir[:3]=[1,2].
 
Same thing applying a ≤ x ≤ b to a 0-base indexed array, as in rul[0,1,2,3,4,5] so that rul[:2]=[0,1,2] or rul[0:2]=[0,1,2].

Given that python is an example of human friendly code language, emphasizing readability, wouldn't having 0 and 1 base indexing and custom slicing methods, improve the thought process when writing and reading the code, by fitting them better to specific contexts or data?
Is there some language that provides both or each language picks only one?

Cheers

Comment: Can you cut your question down to the relevant programming parts? The "alot of discussion" is distracting from the actual question.

Comment: In Visual Basic, you are able to define the lower and upper bound values when defining an array. The lower bound can be 0, 1, 100, anything.

Comment: Given how much confusion it can cause when a `for` loop uses `<=` instead of `<` in languages like C or Java, I doubt mixing conventions for whether a slice includes its endpoint would actually increase readability.

Comment: This is a common discomfort experienced by newbies when learning programming. In this stage, it is normal to try to argue for making languages more natural or context dependent. However, you will soon realise that these type of suggestions add language bloat and unneccessary complexity, harder to reason about code, and would break backwards compatibility (lets say you have a suite of classes function dealing with indexes, you would need to handle the conversion of convention on your end if you are using 1-based, radial, or cow-based indexing). Having 0-based used widely is very convenient.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Why are both arguments coupling indexing method and slciing?

https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/ewd08xx/EWD831.PDF
http://python-history.blogspot.pt/2013/10/why-python-uses-0-based-indexing.html

Imagine a natural numbers array class.

1.>>>L=[0,1,2,3]
2. >>>nL=naturalArray(1,2,3,4)
3. >>>print L[-1:1]
4. []
5. >>>print L[0:2]
6. [0,1]
7. >>>print nL[0:2]
8. {}
9. >>>print nL[1:3]
10. {1,2}

Same behavior of a ≤ x < b  with either 0-based and 1-based. Of course I was avoiding coming up with implementation tricks as that's a whole new topic

PS: Comments suck...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be possible to have different indexing bases or slicing conventions in the same language, and some languages do it that way. For example, Ruby has `a..b` for a range including `b` and `a...b` for a range excluding `b`, and Perl lets you change the array indexing base with [`$[`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html). However, supporting such features adds complexity to a language that may not be worth the benefits. Ruby's syntax is more complex for having `..` and `...`, and Perl discourages `$[` because it's so confusing.

One of Python's design principles, from [PEP 20](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/), is that

> There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.

Python tries to make things like this standard and uniform. Making the design decisions that Ruby or Perl made would go against that philosophy.

Comment: Apparently is not so obvious... Imagine they keep the slicing untouched, at lest a new class could done NaturalArray so that.

x= NaturalArray(1,2,3,4)
and when you print a[1,3] it would return say {1,2}. so the same slicing method but the index "pointing" is different.

I don't see why explanations to this are always coupling indexing with slicing.

Cheers

Comment: @probiner: My explanation doesn't couple indexing and slicing. The Ruby example has both slicing conventions, but only one indexing convention, and the Perl example has both indexing conventions, but I don't have any idea what indexing is like in Perl. As for the NaturalArray class, the same argument applies: the complexity it adds isn't worth the benefits. No code that expects standard indexing could use a NaturalArray, and just about all Python code in existence expects standard indexing. A NaturalArray would lose all interoperability with existing code just to change the indexing.